# How can I mix a StackedBarChart and a LineChart in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx-8

I have a StackedBarChart ready... I would like to add a LineChart in the same chart, in order to show a "maximum level"... how can I do that?

Comment: btw, remove javafx tag as it corresponds to a script-version of javafx (1.3 version)

Answer (score 3):

RFE : https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-22949

There is no way now, except implementing it by yourself.

Comment: Alexander, I have created an overwritten version of StackedBarChart. It's called ParetoChart, it allows to insert a line which is also shown in the chart. I see you pasted a link in your first reply, is there a way I can upload it there? If not, I'll just copy it here itself.

Comment: By line you mean Line(X, Y, X1, Y1), or line like in area chart with several segments?

Comment: There are several things, which you can do with that. 1. register yourself on javafx-jira.kenai.com - that is just javafx bugtracker. nothing special. And add your implementation as attachment to the issue. With according comment. 2. Add this code here as answer. Possibly it will be helpful for others. 3. If it is implemented well - you can talk to developers, possibly it could be added to some open-source project like controlsfx, or openjfx... - but it depends only on developers opinion.

Answer (score 0):

```
/*
 *
 * This class overwrites XYChart, it allows to have a StackedBarChart and
 * additionally to have a "line", this line can be passes as parameter exactly 
 * the same way as when a StackedBarChart is created, but adding the title "Limit".
 * example:
 * ------------------------------------------------
 *       ObservableList<XYChart.Series> barChartData = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
 *               new ParetoChart.Series("Serie # 1", FXCollections.observableArrayList(
 *                   stackedBarCharts)),
 *               new ParetoChart.Series("Limit", FXCollections.observableArrayList(
 *                   limit))
 *       );
 *        XYChart chart = new ParetoChart(xAxis, yAxis, barChartData, 0);
 * 
 * 
 * Where stackedBarCharts and limit are Lists with the corresponding values.
 * ---------------------------------------------
 * @author Juan Jose Robles - robles.gomez.juan@gmail.com
 *
 */


import java.util.*;
import javafx.animation.*;
import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Orientation;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.util.Duration;
import com.sun.javafx.charts.Legend;
import com.sun.javafx.css.StyleableDoubleProperty;
import com.sun.javafx.css.StyleableProperty;
import com.sun.javafx.css.converters.SizeConverter;
import javafx.beans.value.WritableValue;
import javafx.scene.chart.*;
import javafx.scene.shape.LineTo;
import javafx.scene.shape.MoveTo;
import javafx.scene.shape.Path;


    /**
     * ParetoChart is a variation of {@link BarChart} that plots bars indicating 
     * data values for a category. The bars can be vertical or horizontal depending 
     * on which axis is a category axis. 
     * The bar for each series is stacked on top of the previous series.
     */
    public class ParetoChart<X, Y> extends XYChart<X, Y> {

        // -------------- PRIVATE FIELDS -------------------------------------------
        private Map<Series, Map<String, Data<X, Y>>> seriesCategoryMap = new HashMap<Series, Map<String, Data<X, Y>>>();
        private Legend legend = new Legend();
        private final Orientation orientation;
        private CategoryAxis categoryAxis;
        private ValueAxis valueAxis;
        private int seriesDefaultColorIndex = 0;
        private Map<Series<X, Y>, String> seriesDefaultColorMap = new HashMap<Series<X, Y>, String>();
        // -------------- PUBLIC PROPERTIES ----------------------------------------
        /** The gap to leave between bars in separate categories */
        private DoubleProperty categoryGap = new StyleableDoubleProperty(10) {
            @Override protected void invalidated() {
                get();
                requestChartLayout();
            }

            @Override
            public Object getBean() {
                return ParetoChart.this;
            }

            @Override
            public String getName() {
                return "categoryGap";
            }

            public StyleableProperty getStyleableProperty() {
                return ParetoChart.StyleableProperties.CATEGORY_GAP;
            }
        };

        public double getCategoryGap() {
            return categoryGap.getValue();
        }

        public void setCategoryGap(double value) {
            categoryGap.setValue(value);
        }

        public DoubleProperty categoryGapProperty() {
            return categoryGap;
        }

        // -------------- CONSTRUCTOR ----------------------------------------------
        /**
         * Construct a new StackedBarChart with the given axis. The two axis should be a ValueAxis/NumberAxis and a CategoryAxis,
         * they can be in either order depending on if you want a horizontal or vertical bar chart.
         *
         * @param xAxis The x axis to use
         * @param yAxis The y axis to use
         */
        public ParetoChart(Axis<X> xAxis, Axis<Y> yAxis) {
            this(xAxis, yAxis, FXCollections.<Series<X, Y>>observableArrayList());
        }

        /**
         * Construct a new ParetoChart with the given axis and data. The two axis should be a ValueAxis/NumberAxis and a
         * CategoryAxis, they can be in either order depending on if you want a horizontal or vertical bar chart.
         *
         * @param xAxis The x axis to use
         * @param yAxis The y axis to use
         * @param data The data to use, this is the actual list used so any changes to it will be reflected in the chart
         */
        public ParetoChart(Axis<X> xAxis, Axis<Y> yAxis, ObservableList<Series<X, Y>> data) {
            super(xAxis, yAxis);
            getStyleClass().add("stacked-bar-chart");
            setLegend(legend);
            if (!((xAxis instanceof ValueAxis && yAxis instanceof CategoryAxis)
                    || (yAxis instanceof ValueAxis && xAxis instanceof CategoryAxis))) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Axis type incorrect, one of X,Y should be CategoryAxis and the other NumberAxis");
            }
            if (xAxis instanceof CategoryAxis) {
                categoryAxis = (CategoryAxis) xAxis;
                valueAxis = (ValueAxis) yAxis;
                orientation = Orientation.VERTICAL;
            } else {
                categoryAxis = (CategoryAxis) yAxis;
                valueAxis = (ValueAxis) xAxis;
                orientation = Orientation.HORIZONTAL;
            }
            setData(data);
        }

        /**
         * Construct a new ParetoChart with the given axis and data. The two axis should be a ValueAxis/NumberAxis and a
         * CategoryAxis, they can be in either order depending on if you want a horizontal or vertical bar chart.
         *
         * @param xAxis The x axis to use
         * @param yAxis The y axis to use
         * @param data The data to use, this is the actual list used so any changes to it will be reflected in the chart
         * @param categoryGap The gap to leave between bars in separate categories
         */
        public ParetoChart(Axis<X> xAxis, Axis<Y> yAxis, ObservableList<Series<X, Y>> data, double categoryGap) {
            this(xAxis, yAxis);
            setData(data);
            setCategoryGap(categoryGap);
        }

        // -------------- METHODS --------------------------------------------------
        @Override protected void dataItemAdded(Series<X, Y> series, int itemIndex, Data<X, Y> item) {
            String category;
            if (orientation == Orientation.VERTICAL) {
                category = (String) item.getXValue();
            } else {
                category = (String) item.getYValue();
            }
            // Don't plot if category does not already exist ?
//        if (!categoryAxis.getCategories().contains(category)) return;

            Map<String, Data<X, Y>> categoryMap = seriesCategoryMap.get(series);

            if (categoryMap == null) {
                categoryMap = new HashMap<String, Data<X, Y>>();
                seriesCategoryMap.put(series, categoryMap);
            }
            categoryMap.put(category, item);
            Node bar = createBar(series, getData().indexOf(series), item, itemIndex);
            if (shouldAnimate()) {
                animateDataAdd(item, bar);
            } else {
                getPlotChildren().add(bar);
            }
        }

        @Override protected void dataItemRemoved(final Data<X, Y> item, final Series<X, Y> series) {
            final Node bar = item.getNode();
            if (shouldAnimate()) {
                Timeline t = createDataRemoveTimeline(item, bar, series);
                t.setOnFinished(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

                    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                        removeDataItemFromDisplay(series, item);
                    }
                });
                t.play();
            } else {
                getPlotChildren().remove(bar);
                removeDataItemFromDisplay(series, item);
            }
        }

        /** @inheritDoc */
        @Override protected void dataItemChanged(Data<X, Y> item) {
            double barVal;
            double currentVal;
            if (orientation == Orientation.VERTICAL) {
                barVal = ((Number) item.getYValue()).doubleValue();
                currentVal = ((Number) getCurrentDisplayedYValue(item)).doubleValue();
            } else {
                barVal = ((Number) item.getXValue()).doubleValue();
                currentVal = ((Number) getCurrentDisplayedXValue(item)).doubleValue();
            }
            if (currentVal > 0 && barVal < 0) { // going from positive to negative
                // add style class negative
                item.getNode().getStyleClass().add("negative");
            } else if (currentVal < 0 && barVal > 0) { // going from negative to positive
                // remove style class negative
                item.getNode().getStyleClass().add("negative");
            }
        }

        private void animateDataAdd(Data<X, Y> item, Node bar) {
            double barVal;
            if (orientation == Orientation.VERTICAL) {
                barVal = ((Number) item.getYValue()).doubleValue();
                if (barVal < 0) {
                    bar.getStyleClass().add("negative");
                }
                item.setYValue(getYAxis().toRealValue(getYAxis().getZeroPosition()));
                setCurrentDisplayedYValue(item, getYAxis().toRealValue(getYAxis().getZeroPosition()));
                getPlotChildren().add(bar);
                item.setYValue(getYAxis().toRealValue(barVal));
                animate(
                        TimelineBuilder.create().keyFrames(
                        new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, new KeyValue(currentDisplayedYValueProperty(item), getCurrentDisplayedYValue(item))),
                        new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(700), new KeyValue(currentDisplayedYValueProperty(item), item.getYValue(), Interpolator.EASE_BOTH))).build());
            } else {
                barVal = ((Number) item.getXValue()).doubleValue();
                if (barVal < 0) {
                    bar.getStyleClass().add("negative");
                }
                item.setXValue(getXAxis().toRealValue(getXAxis().getZeroPosition()));
                setCurrentDisplayedXValue(item, getXAxis().toRealValue(getXAxis().getZeroPosition()));
                getPlotChildren().add(bar);
                item.setXValue(getXAxis().toRealValue(barVal));
                animate(
                        TimelineBuilder.create().keyFrames(
                        new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, new KeyValue(currentDisplayedXValueProperty(item), getCurrentDisplayedXValue(item))),
                        new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(700), new KeyValue(currentDisplayedXValueProperty(item), item.getXValue(), Interpolator.EASE_BOTH))).build());
            }
        }

        /** @inheritDoc */
        @Override protected void seriesAdded(Series<X, Y> series, int seriesIndex) {
            String defaultColorStyleClass = "default-color" + (seriesDefaultColorIndex % 8);
            seriesDefaultColorMap.put(series, defaultColorStyleClass);
            seriesDefaultColorIndex++;
            // handle any data already in series
            // create entry in the map
            Map<String, Data<X, Y>> categoryMap = new HashMap<String, Data<X, Y>>();
            for (int j = 0; j < series.getData().size(); j++) {
                Data<X, Y> item = series.getData().get(j);
                Node bar = createBar(series, seriesIndex, item, j);
                String category;
                if (orientation == Orientation.VERTICAL) {
                    category = (String) item.getXValue();
                } else {
                    category = (String) item.getYValue();
                }
                categoryMap.put(category, item);
                if (shouldAnimate()) {
                    animateDataAdd(item, bar);
                } else {
                    getPlotChildren().add(bar);
                }
            }
            if (categoryMap.size() > 0) {
                seriesCategoryMap.put(series, categoryMap);
            }
            Path seriesPath = new Path();
            seriesPath.getStyleClass().setAll("candlestick-average-line","series"+seriesIndex);
            series.setNode(seriesPath);
            getPlotChildren().add(seriesPath);            
        }

        private Timeline createDataRemoveTimeline(Data<X, Y> item, final Node bar, final Series<X, Y> series) {
            Timeline t = new Timeline();
            if (orientation == Orientation.VERTICAL) {
                item.setYValue(getYAxis().toRealValue(getYAxis().getZeroPosition()));
                t.getKeyFrames().addAll(
                        new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, new KeyValue(currentDisplayedYValueProperty(item), getCurrentDisplayedYValue(item))),
                        new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(700), new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

                    @Override
                    public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                        getPlotChildren().remove(bar);
                    }
                },
                        new KeyValue(currentDisplayedYValueProperty(item), item.getYValue(), Interpolator.EASE_BOTH)));
            } else {
                item.setXValue(getXAxis().toRealValue(getXAxis().getZeroPosition()));
                t.getKeyFrames().addAll(
                        new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, new KeyValue(currentDisplayedXValueProperty(item), getCurrentDisplayedXValue(item))),
                        new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(700), new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

                    @Override
                    public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                        getPlotChildren().remove(bar);
                    }
                },
                        new KeyValue(currentDisplayedXValueProperty(item), item.getXValue(), Interpolator.EASE_BOTH)));
            }
            return t;
        }

        @Override protected void seriesRemoved(final Series<X, Y> series) {
            // remove all symbol nodes
            if (shouldAnimate()) {
                ParallelTransition pt = new ParallelTransition();
                pt.setOnFinished(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

                    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                        removeSeriesFromDisplay(series);
                    }
                });
                for (Data<X, Y> d : series.getData()) {
                    final Node bar = d.getNode();
                    // Animate series deletion
                    if (getSeriesSize() > 1) {
                        for (int j = 0; j < series.getData().size(); j++) {
                            Data<X, Y> item = series.getData().get(j);
                            Timeline t = createDataRemoveTimeline(item, bar, series);
                            pt.getChildren().add(t);
                        }
                    } else {
                        // fade out last series
                        FadeTransition ft = new FadeTransition(Duration.millis(700), bar);
                        ft.setFromValue(1);
                        ft.setToValue(0);
                        ft.setOnFinished(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

                            @Override
                            public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                                getPlotChildren().remove(bar);
                            }
                        });
                        pt.getChildren().add(ft);
                    }
                }
                pt.play();
            } else {
                for (Data<X, Y> d : series.getData()) {
                    final Node bar = d.getNode();
                    getPlotChildren().remove(bar);
                }
                removeSeriesFromDisplay(series);
            }
        }

        /** @inheritDoc */
        @Override protected void updateAxisRange() {
            // This override is necessary to update axis range based on cumulative Y value for the
            // Y axis instead of the inherited way where the max value in the data range is used.
            final Axis<X> xa = getXAxis();
            final Axis<Y> ya = getYAxis();
            if (xa.isAutoRanging()) {
                List xData = new ArrayList<Number>();
                if (xa instanceof CategoryAxis) {
                    xData.addAll(categoryAxis.getCategories());
                } else {
                    int catIndex = 0;
                    for (String category : categoryAxis.getCategories()) {
                        int index = 0;
                        double totalX = 0;
                        Iterator<Series<X, Y>> seriesIterator = getDisplayedSeriesIterator();
                        while (seriesIterator.hasNext()) {
                            Series<X, Y> series = seriesIterator.next();
                            final Data<X, Y> item = getDataItem(series, index, catIndex, category);
                            totalX += xa.toNumericValue(item.getXValue());
                        }
                        xData.add(totalX);
                        catIndex++;
                    }
                }
                xa.invalidateRange(xData);
            }
            if (ya.isAutoRanging()) {
                List yData = new ArrayList<Number>();
                if (ya instanceof CategoryAxis) {
                    yData.addAll(categoryAxis.getCategories());
                } else {
                    int catIndex = 0;
                    for (String category : categoryAxis.getCategories()) {
                        int index = 0;
                        double totalY = 0;
                        Iterator<Series<X, Y>> seriesIterator = getDisplayedSeriesIterator();
                        while (seriesIterator.hasNext()) {
                            Series<X, Y> series = seriesIterator.next();
                            final Data<X, Y> item = getDataItem(series, index, catIndex, category);
                            if(item != null) 
                                totalY += ya.toNumericValue(item.getYValue());
                        }
                        yData.add(totalY);
                        catIndex++;
                    }
                }
                ya.invalidateRange(yData);
            }
        }

        /** @inheritDoc */
        @Override protected void layoutPlotChildren() {
            double catSpace = categoryAxis.getCategorySpacing();
            // calculate bar spacing
            final double availableBarSpace = catSpace - getCategoryGap();
            final double barWidth = availableBarSpace;
            final double barOffset = -((catSpace - getCategoryGap()) / 2);
            final double zeroPos = valueAxis.getZeroPosition();
            // update bar positions and sizes
            int catIndex = 0;

            for (String category : categoryAxis.getCategories()) {
                int index = 0;
                int currentHeight = 0;
                Iterator<Series<X, Y>> seriesIterator = getDisplayedSeriesIterator();
                Path seriesPath = null;
                while (seriesIterator.hasNext()) {
                    Series<X, Y> series = seriesIterator.next();

                    final Data<X, Y> item = getDataItem(series, index, catIndex, category);
                    double valPos = 0;
                    double categoryPos = 0;

                    if (item != null) {
                        final Node bar = item.getNode();

                        if (orientation == Orientation.VERTICAL) {

                            //Results res = (Results)getCurrentDisplayedYValue(item);
                            categoryPos = getXAxis().getDisplayPosition(getCurrentDisplayedXValue(item));
                            valPos = getYAxis().getDisplayPosition(getCurrentDisplayedYValue(item));
                            //valPos = getYAxis().res.getDuration();
                        } else {
                            categoryPos = getYAxis().getDisplayPosition(getCurrentDisplayedYValue(item));
                            valPos = getXAxis().getDisplayPosition(getCurrentDisplayedXValue(item));
                        }
                        final double bottom = currentHeight + Math.min(valPos, zeroPos);
                        final double top = currentHeight + Math.max(valPos, zeroPos);
                        if (orientation == Orientation.VERTICAL) {
                            if (series.getName().equals("Limit")){
                                bar.resizeRelocate(0,
                                    bottom, 0, top - bottom);
                            } 
                            else{
                                bar.resizeRelocate(categoryPos + barOffset,
                                    bottom, barWidth, top - bottom);

                            }
                        } else {
                            //noinspection SuspiciousNameCombination
                            bar.resizeRelocate(bottom,
                                    categoryPos + barOffset,
                                    top - bottom, barWidth);
                        }

                        currentHeight -= top - bottom;
                        index++;
                    }

                    if (series.getName().equals("Limit")){
                        if (series.getNode() instanceof Path) {
                            seriesPath = (Path)series.getNode();
                            //seriesPath.getElements().clear();
                        }                    
                        if (seriesPath != null) {
                            if (seriesPath.getElements().isEmpty()) {
                                seriesPath.getElements().add(new MoveTo( categoryPos,valPos));
                            } else {
                                seriesPath.getElements().add(new LineTo( categoryPos,valPos));
                            }
                        }                        
                    }                    

                }
                catIndex++;
            }

        }

        /**
         * Computes the size of series linked list
         * @return size of series linked list
         */
        int getSeriesSize() {
            int count = 0;
            Iterator<Series<X, Y>> seriesIterator = getDisplayedSeriesIterator();
            while (seriesIterator.hasNext()) {
                seriesIterator.next();
                count++;
            }
            return count;
        }

        /**
         * This is called whenever a series is added or removed and the legend needs to be updated
         */
        @Override protected void updateLegend() {
            legend.getItems().clear();
            if (getData() != null) {
                for (int seriesIndex = 0; seriesIndex < getData().size(); seriesIndex++) {
                    Series series = getData().get(seriesIndex);
                    String name = series.getName();
                    if ("".equals(name)){
                        name = "Undefined";
                    }
                    if (name.equals("Limit")){
                        continue;
                    }
                    Legend.LegendItem legenditem = new Legend.LegendItem(name);
                    String defaultColorStyleClass = seriesDefaultColorMap.get(series);
                    legenditem.getSymbol().getStyleClass().addAll("chart-bar", "series" + seriesIndex, "bar-legend-symbol",
                            defaultColorStyleClass);
                    legend.getItems().add(legenditem);

                }
            }
            if (legend.getItems().size() > 0) {
                if (getLegend() == null) {
                    setLegend(legend);
                }
            } else {
                setLegend(null);
            }
        }

        private Node createBar(Series series, int seriesIndex, final Data item, int itemIndex) {
            Node bar = item.getNode();
            if (bar == null) {
                bar = new StackPane();
                item.setNode(bar);
            }
            String defaultColorStyleClass = seriesDefaultColorMap.get(series);
            bar.getStyleClass().setAll("chart-bar", "series" + seriesIndex, "data" + itemIndex, defaultColorStyleClass);
            return bar;
        }

        private Data<X, Y> getDataItem(Series<X, Y> series, int seriesIndex, int itemIndex, String category) {
            Map<String, Data<X, Y>> catmap = seriesCategoryMap.get(series);
            if (catmap == null) return null;
            return catmap.get(category);
        }



// -------------- STYLESHEET HANDLING ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
      * Super-lazy instantiation pattern from Bill Pugh.
      * @treatAsPrivate implementation detail
      */
     private static class StyleableProperties {

         private static final StyleableProperty<ParetoChart,Number> CATEGORY_GAP = 
             new StyleableProperty<ParetoChart,Number>("-fx-category-gap",
                 SizeConverter.getInstance(), 10.0)  {

            @Override
            public boolean isSettable(ParetoChart node) {
                return node.categoryGap == null || !node.categoryGap.isBound();
            }

            @Override
            public WritableValue<Number> getWritableValue(ParetoChart node) {
                 return node.categoryGapProperty();
            }
        };

         private static final List<StyleableProperty> STYLEABLES;

         static {

            final List<StyleableProperty> styleables =
                new ArrayList<StyleableProperty>(XYChart.impl_CSS_STYLEABLES());
            Collections.addAll(styleables,
                CATEGORY_GAP
            );
            STYLEABLES = Collections.unmodifiableList(styleables);
         }
    }

     /**
     * @treatAsPrivate implementation detail
     * @deprecated This is an internal API that is not intended for use and will be removed in the next version
     */
    @Deprecated
    public static List<StyleableProperty> impl_CSS_STYLEABLES() {
        return ParetoChart.StyleableProperties.STYLEABLES;
    }

    /**
     * RT-19263
     * @treatAsPrivate implementation detail
     * @deprecated This is an experimental API that is not intended for general use and is subject to change in future versions
     */
    @Deprecated
    public List<StyleableProperty> impl_getStyleableProperties() {
        return impl_CSS_STYLEABLES();
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you cut this down to a smaller snippet showing your problem?  Not many people are willing to read that much code.

Comment: Creating a GitHub Repo or Gist and linking to that would be much more helpful, than posting a quite big class directly to Stack Overflow.